# I need some help making a regex search

Tags: regex, grep, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am working on making a regex to recognize a function for my new programming language's syntax highlighting file for vim. I cannot for the life of me understand how to make it match this though.

it would need to match all functions in an example like this:

```
int addFive() {

}

addFive()

int addFive()
{
}

int value = addFive ()

addFive(int number)

void sum ( string hello )

etc...
```

but cannot figure it out.
here is what I managed to figure out: `[a-zA-Z]*()$`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the all of the syntax you're trying to match, but something like this might work:
`[a-zA-Z]+?\s*?\(.*?\)`

`[a-zA-Z]+?` matches alphabet characters, if you want numbers as well you could do `[a-zA-Z0-9]+?`

`\s*?` matches possible whitespace between the function name and the parentheses

`\(` matches the first parenthesis

`.*?` matches any characters inside the parentheses

`\)` matches the last parenthesis

test it out: https://regex101.com/r/L2guif/1

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `grep` to identify text across lines with `-z` option with `-o` option.

```
grep -z -o ")[[:space:]]\+{[^}]*}"
```

---

But that is a bad idea.

If the function may contain brackets.

For example:

```
int funct1 () {
 int 1;
 for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   print i;
 }
}
```

The RegExp will match the closing bracket, in internal `for-loop` bracket.

RegExp cannot include logic.

RegExp difficult to distinguish `for-loop` or `if-condition` from a function.

You probably need lexical analyzer like `lex` to identify the structure of your program.

Answer (score 0):

For functions like:

```
int addFive() {
    blah blah
    blah...
}
```

You can do this: `/^.*(.*).*{\_.\{-}.*}`

Best regards.